# Error: spawn lein ENOENT in atom proto-repl on windows

Tags: clojure, atom-editor

I am trying to run the clojure proto-repl in atom on windows but hitting this error. I can't seem to fix it and so I am turning to SO for advice.

```
Error starting repl: Error: spawn lein ENOENT
You may need to configure the lein path in proto-repl settings

REPL Closed
```

I have set the lein path in proto-repl settings already. I have tried running it administrator and running from command line. No luck.

```
C:\Program Files\.lein\bin\lein.bat
```

Do you think this is something to do with lein being in Program Files? I used to have a similar issue with Ruby gems but I like to keep my programs where they belong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with Proto REPL as described [here](https://github.com/jasongilman/proto-repl/issues/13). This should be fixed now in version 0.5.1. Please [file an issue](https://github.com/jasongilman/proto-repl/issues) if you encounter any more problems.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem too, in version 0.15.0. I was able to fix it by using *forward* slashes instead of backslashes, when setting the lein path in proto-repl settings. Forward slashes have worked fine on Windows for years.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around with relative and absolute file path, I used the file tree convention for Linux and it worked! for example: C:/User/User\Name/.lein/lib/lein.bat

Essentially, any file paths with multiple word string need to be concat'd with a '\' like in Linux systems. Hope this helps! This can be frustrating as it's a wonderful Clojure REPL suite.

Answer (score 0):

I still ran into this issue on proto-repl 1.4.21.

Path to the directory containing lein.bat with forward slashes worked for me:

```
C:/Users/username/.lein
```